Is it plausible for a volcanic moon to provide material for rock-based rings for a planet, as well as regular orbital bombardment?
I've recently had an idea after reading about how the Moon used to be volcanic. If, theoretically, the volcanism was powerful enough, a moon or satellite of some sort could launch volcanic byproducts into the atmosphere down to the earth below, like the Late Orbital Bombardment period. Some could escape the pull, and eventually accumulate into rings around a celestial body.
However, I am not a smart man. I would like to know, is this concept plausible in terms of purely theoretical terms? I will do the math and physics later, I want to know if I should bother investing the time into researching this subject to add to my world.
If there are any real-life examples, please let me know of them. I have done some basic investigation, and to my knowledge, there are no instances of this existing with our current information.

(a) I removed the [tag:internal-consistency] tag because it cannot be used along with the [tag:science-fiction] tag, has specific rules you have not followed, and has a specific goal you do not have. (b) As stated in the [help/on-topic], we're here to help you build an imaginary world of your own creation. This does not appear to be a worldbuilding question. It does appear to be a Real World question better suited to [astronomy.se].
